# Replace each match in string with a random value from array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a long string in cell C2 with the match ( # ) multiple times across the string length - I want to assign one value for each match, from my array object "rand". Then rewrite my new string back to cell C2.

My example string can be "This is a string # and this is also a string# but this is a string too#"

I want to add a random value from my rand array to each instance of "#"

```
function mergeAll() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1iXQxyL3URe1X1FgbZ76mEFAxLnxegyDzXOMF6WQ5Yqs"));
  var sheet1 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de porcentajes");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("preoutput");
  var sheet3 = doc.getSheetByName("output") ;

  var range = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var data = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    var rand = [[" así como "],[" también "],[" asimismo "],[" igualmente "],[" asimismo "],[" de igual modo "],[" de igual manera "],[" de igual forma "],[" del mismo modo "],[" por su parte "],[" de la misma manera "],[" de la misma forma "],[" por otro lado "]];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length);
    var aditivo = rand.splice(randomIndex,1);
  }
  sheet3.getRange("C2").setValue(data.join("#"));
  var obj = sheet3.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var count = (obj.match(/#/g) || []).length;

  for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    var string = obj.replace(/#/g,aditivo);
    aditivo[count++];
    sheet3.getRange("C2").setValue(string);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an incomplete example.  The term data is not defined.

Comment: I thought shortening the code to the relevant part would be helpful so I have included the whole code now.  I updated the description too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're overthinking this one, hopefully this solution & explanation will help.

The loops you've written in your implementation have some problems. In the first one, you're re-declaring your variables each iteration, so the final value of `aditivo()` is what is set in the last iteration. The other loop is infinite because you are incrementing the counter variable each iteration with `aditivo[counter++]`, so `j` is always less than `counter`.

Also, your string replace is not working as expected. You are replacing every occurrence of '#' with the contents of the array `aditivo()`. In your current code `aditivo()` has only 1 value, but if `aditivo()` had more members the replace would put *all* of them between *each* substring.

In the end you actually don't need any loops to do what you need: all you have to do is run your global replace over your joined string using a function to return a random replacement string, rather than using a fixed replacement. Here's a quick implementation, i hope this does what you want -- you could write a better one:

```
function mergeAll() {    
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("<obfucscated>"));
  var sheet1 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de porcentajes");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("preoutput");
  var sheet3 = doc.getSheetByName("output") ;
  var data = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var str = data.join("#"); // join your data array into one string
  // make rand[] into a 1-dimensional array so that we can address the elements more easily

  var rand = [" así como "," también "," asimismo "," igualmente "," asimismo "," de igual modo "," de igual manera "," de igual forma "," del mismo modo "," por su parte "," de la misma manera "," de la misma forma "," por otro lado "];

  // now do the global replace on str, 
  //   but use a function to give us a random replacement string
  str = str.replace(/#/g, function(m){ return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)]; });

  // now write the updated str back to the spreadsheet
  sheet3.getRange("C2").setValue(str);
}
```

Comment: That's just great, as you have simplified the solution in a couple of lines. Very elegant. Thanks for the lesson. I have choosen your answer as the best and correct one!